# Dynamic width with inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have two `<div>` elements, one next to the other. Both have the CSS attribute `display: inline-block;`. Now the second `<div>` element has a fixed width of 100 px, whereas the first `<div>` element doesn't have a fixed width: it depends on the size of the window.

My problem is that the first `<div>` element will spread over 100% vertically if the window is narrow. I would like to restrict its width to 100% minus 100px, so that both `<div>` elements can align one next to the other at all times.

I've looked at posts with similar questions, but none really dealt with the case of `inline-block`.

**EDIT**: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3sXu/ I want the first `<div>` to provide some room for the second `<div>` on the same line.

Comment: code samples would help or if you have the time a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no particular reason to use `display: inline-block` to do this.

Here's a clean implementation using floats instead: http://jsfiddle.net/y3sXu/14/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="DivB">b</div>
    <div id="DivA">a</div>
</div>

#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#DivA {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#DivB {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That solution works the best. What do the `overflow: hidden;` do exactly? That's still a little mysterious to me!

Comment: `overflow: hidden` on `#container` [contains the floats](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59). `overflow: hidden` on `#DivA` is [explained here](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats).

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but has some weight in Google so I thought I'd update it with a new answer. A more modern way to accomplish this is to stick  with `display:inline-block;` and use `calc` for the width of the variable element.

So long as you have one fixed width inline element `width: 150px`, you can offset the variable width element by the fixed width `calc(100% - 150px)`.

Your code should look like this:

```
.fixed-width-element {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}

.variable-width-element {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

Comment: In addition make sure to add space between numbers and the '-'. eg incorrect: calc(100%-150px); correct: calc(100% - 150px);

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand what you are asking for. http://jsfiddle.net/y3sXu/6/

I have gone for a traditional two column layout, as it seems like the best way to solve your problem.

`float` has been used to ensure that the right hand div always sits on the right, and `margin-left` to keep the left `div` away. `overflow:hidden` is used a cheap and cheerful clearfix.

Comment: Nice! I was trying something like that but the only thing I was missing was the overflow:hidden... good job!

Answer (score 1):

best way I can figure doing it is with absolute positioning:

```
div#TextB{
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:10px;
}

div#master{
    margin-right:120px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vnxr7/1

Comment: that's because it kind of is. XD Sorry, but I've never done something like that with css and html alone.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the outer div a padding of 50px on both left and right side

**EDIT**
Place this where u want to put the gap:

```
<div width="100px" height="1em">&nbsp;<div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. There is padding, but instead of space for the second `<div>`, it's just whitespace.

Comment: Then do u want there should be a 100px free space and then the content of the second div should be shown ?

Comment: See my edit. Is this what u want ? Dont try this on fiddle but on the page u want it. Fiddle might have got some bugs in it

Comment: Well there was a bug when i tried to do some positioning around.

Comment: @kritya if in doubt, you can use show at the end of your fiddle to remove the frames: `http://jsfiddle.net/y3sXu/show`

Comment: ooops i forgot to paste this : &nbsp; in the empty div. Put this there.

Answer (score 0):

There is one very ugly solution:
Set the overflow of the outer div to hidden, take the div out of the dom using position:relative, setting the left to -100px and the width to 100%.

You have to play around with the display, position and left/top etc. or get back with some more details so one could know what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yuck. I've provided a jsfiddle.

Comment: I know, I'm not happy either. There are better solutions postet here.

Answer (score 0):

what  about this ?

```
div {
    background:green;
    margin-right:100px;
}


#TextB{
    width:100px;
    background:red;
    float:right;
    margin:0px;
}
```

[Updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/y3sXu/7/)